# lockHardwareCanvas is slower than lockCanvas when unlocking

Tags: java, android, locking, surfaceview, hardware-acceleration

I am making an app in Java Android with custom drawing on a hardware accelerated SurfaceView. On this i use a lot of paths, rectangles and most importantly shadows made by using a BlurMaskFilter. After adding a lot of shadows (that i am drawing as small and few of as possible) the frames of course start to drop beneath 60fps and i thought this could easily be fixed by using `surfaceHolder.lockHardwareCanvas();` instead of `surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();`.

The problem is: Although the rendering time of the Hardware Accelerated Canvas is about tenth of the non-Hardware Accelerated one, the fps doesn't increase nearly as much as the speed increase should indicate.

Maybe something other than rendering is taking up the time? In the Android Studio Profiler it seems as if the `surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost();` is taking way too much time (30-100 ms), when too much happens and the frames will thus drop rapidly (only in the HA-Canvas).
This means that the HA framerate is usually 60fps, but will sometimes drop to 40-45, while the non-HA will keep a steady 50-55fps.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening with the unlocking of the canvas? Am i doing something wrong or do i just have to draw less on the screen?
This is my SurfaceView draw method:

```
public void draw(DrawMethod drawMethod) {
    canvas = null;

    try {
        if(holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            canvas = holder.lockHardwareCanvas();
        }
        if(canvas != null) {
            synchronized (holder) {
                drawMethod.draw(canvas);    //Draws everything on screen
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if(canvas != null) {
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```